# How is Apache Camel's Enrich EIP Supposed to Work with File Endpoints?

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix, blueprint-osgi

I am trying to learn how to use Apache Camel by writing simple routes that use the various EIPs. My mentor has suggested Apache ServiceMix as a good server for testing simple routes, so I'm using Apache ServiceMix 5.1.0. Currently, I'm trying to make a route that reads a request from a file, replaces the contents of the request with a response from a second file, and writes that response to a third file.

Ideally, the second file wouldn't be deleted; I would eventually want to use this pattern in other self-tutorial routes, and the second file would mimic the response of a webservice. However, I'm just trying to get this to work right now, so I'm not complicating things with options like `noop`.

If I've read [the Apache Camel Wiki page for the Content Enricher](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) correctly, omitting the aggregation strategy from an `enrich` EIP will make Camel discard the contents of the message and replace it with the body obtained from the resource. So, I thought this Camel Route would do what I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route>
            <from uri="file:camel/inMessage/?fileName=replaceMe.txt" />
            <enrich uri="file:camel/storedResponse/?fileName=withThis.txt" />
            <to uri="file:camel/outMessage/?fileName=output.txt" />
        </route>
    </camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

What actually happens is that the contents of `camel/storedResponse/withThis.txt` is replaced with the contents of `camel/inMessage/replaceMe.txt`. The file `camel/outmessage/output.txt` is created, but it contains the contents of `replaceMe.txt`, not `withThis.txt`.

Since I'm still new to Camel, I assume the problem is just me misreading something in the documentation, or overlooking an obvious configuration problem.

For what it's worth, here are the contents of the files before starting the route.

```
replaceMe.txt
This is the message sent. It should not appear in the response.

withThis.txt
This is the file stored in the server. The response should contain this text.

output.txt does not yet exist.
```

Here are the contents of the files after the route has completed.

```
replaceMe.txt has been deleted.

withThis.txt
This is the message sent. It should not appear in the response.

output.txt
This is the message sent. It should not appear in the response.
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Camel doc](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html):

> **enrich** uses a Producer to obtain the additional data. It is usually used for Request Reply messaging, for instance to invoke an external web service. **pollEnrich** on the other hand uses a Polling Consumer to obtain the additional data. It is usually used for Event Message messaging, for instance to read a file or download a FTP file.

If using `enrich`, then the content of `withThis.txt` is replaced with the content of `replaceMe.txt`, and this is not what you want. Use `pollEnrich` instead:

```
 <pollEnrich uri="file:camel/storedResponse/?fileName=withThis.txt" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried a more complicated example where `pollEnrich` resulted in the route hanging, so I was hesitant to try it again. Does this mean there is an error in the Camel documentation where it says, "The aggregation strategy is optional. If you do not provide it Camel will by default just use the body obtained from the resource."? In this case, the resource is `withThis.txt`, but `enrich` ignores the content of the resource.

Comment: @JacobMorleyCarson The documentation is correct: the aggregation strategy is optional. Use `enrich` for producer (`to`), e.g. invoking a web service or writing data. Use `pollEnrich` for consumer (`from`), e.g. reading data from a file.

Comment: So, the first sentence I quoted from the Camel documentation is correct. The second I quoted says, "If you do not provide it Camel will by default just use the body obtained from the resource." That's the part that seems to be incorrect. I think the resource is the endpoint given in the `enrich` tag; in this case, it's `withThis.txt`. Despite the documentation saying that Camel will use the body obtained from the resource, Camel is instead discarding the body obtained from the resource.

Comment: @JacobMorleyCarson But, `enrich` must not be used for **reading** files.

Comment: I think I see what I was misunderstanding. If I understand now, `enrich` receives an exchange. It then produces its own exchange that it sends to the endpoint. The `file` endpoint receives the produced exchange and interprets it as if it were in a `to` tag. `enrich` then sends whatever it gets from its `uri` attribute - the `file` endpoint - to the next part of the route. The sentence that I quoted was referring to the exchange `enrich` produces, but I thought it was referring to the exchange `enrich` receives. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

enrich works like a to
Your route is actually **writing** the body received from replaceMe.txt to withThis.txt without changing anything to the body. Hence the final result
pollEnrich would need to be used to actually **read** from withThis.txt